# How to get data in Laravel using POST method in JSON Object?

Tags: php, json, post, laravel-5

here is my **route.php**

```
Route::post('users' , array('uses'  => 'Userscontroller@index'));
```

This is my **Userscontroller.php**

```
public function index()
    {
        $email_id = Input::get('email_id');
        $name = Input::get('name');

        return $email_id. ' ' .$name;
    }
```

When i run this in postman I get **error** as

> '>' **unexpected** in JSON

.

Where m I missing?

Thank You.

Comment: Are you comfortable with json in core php?

Comment: Yes. I have to use Post method to get data.

Comment: Are you post normal data and want in json format, am I correct.

Comment: Here It is. {
   "email_id" : "xyz@gmail.com",
   "name" : "xyz"
}

Answer (score 5):

if you send json like this:

```
{"user":{"name":"abc","code":134}}
```

in laravel controller:

```
$data =  $request->json()->all(); //read json in request
return response()->json($data);  //send json respond
```

Comment: use Content-type to your request: application/json

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
public function index()
{
   //if you want to get json data in your controller do this:
    Request::json()->all();

    //Return json data to your view script like this:
    return response()->json(['email_id'=>$email_id, 'name'=>$name]);
}
```

Comment: In my above question. I have mentioned my **route.php** and **Userscontroller.php**. I want data using post method in JSON Object.

Comment: There is not json data.@Bhavin Shah

Comment: Request::json()->all();

        $email_id = Input::get('email_id');
        $name = Input::get('name');

        return response()->json_encode(['email_id'=>$email_id, 'name'=>$name]);

Comment: I have this code for getting data using post method.

Comment: dd(Request::json()->all()) what you see?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
 public function index(Request $request)
    {
       $dataArray = $request->get('data');
       $data = json_decode($dataArray, true);
       return 'Name: '.$data['name'].', Email: '.$data['email_id'];
    }
```

Send your data into `data` tag.